# change background color every 5 press with php only

Tags: php, html

I need to make a button with PHP. The fifth time when pressed should change my background color with a random one and keep it of every five presses. after another 5 press my background color should change again and keep it until next 5 press

Here is my code

```
<?php 



session_start();
$_SESSION['counter'] = isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter'] : 0;
if($_POST['sub']) {
 $_SESSION['counter']++;

 echo "<br/>";
 echo $culoare;
echo "<body bgcolor='<?phpecho $culoare;?>'></body>";
}

?>

</head>
<body >

<form action='' method="post">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="click" />
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php print $_POST['counter']; ?>" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @jilltieffel - please edit the code into the question in future.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? You have the code.

When the form is submitted, get the value of the counter in the hidden field. If the value is not equal to 5, increment it and pass it again to your view to store it the hidden field. When the value is equal to 5, change your background color and set the counter to 0.

You need to keep your color in an hidden field to if you want to have the same color five times.

```
<?php

// First call.
if(!isset($_POST)) {
    $color = "rgb(" . rand(0, 255) . "," . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . ")";
    $counter = 0;
}

else {
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $counter = $_POST['counter'];
}

if($counter == 5) {
    $color = "rgb(" . rand(0, 255) . "," . rand(0,255) . "," . rand(0,255) . ")";
    $counter = 1; // Set to 1 if you want to change bg color on fifth click.
}

else {
    $counter++;
}

?>

<div style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="color" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I think that something like this may work.

Comment: Also, I suggest you to use a templating system if you can. Mix HTML and PHP code in the same file as you do here is now archaic.